# Redis - How to load multiple rows with the same key into Redis?

Tags: redis, key

What is the best approach to load CSV with example:

id1,mike,123
id1,joe,234
id2,ben,235
id2,jack,445

The need is to query based on a first column (key) but there are keys that are repeating...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use HASHES because you're trying to do an object representation. According to best practices, you should use it every time it is possible; the key would be your first column and the value would be the repeating lines.

If you want more information about Redis data types, you can go on: https://redis.io/topics/data-types

Also this link is very useful for optimizing Redis: https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization

From the memory optimization page:

> **Use hashes when possible**
>
> Small hashes are encoded in a very small space, so you should try
> representing your data using hashes every time it is possible